# Mobile version duplicates the languages

Tags: magento

I have a Magento site with one domain, one store and a store view for each language. I need to add a mobile version of the site and have that in all the languages.

If I add another store for the mobile version then store views for each language, I land up duplicating all the languages in the admin area.

The only solution I can see is to have 2 instances of Magento. One with all the store structures (acting front end – install A) and one with all the product (acting backend – install B)

Install A would have two stores and all languages per store and install B would have one store and store views for each language so we only manage each language once.

We would then need to connect these two Magento instances using the API (xml with SOAP). This way we manage each language once and the front end can have as many variations of that language as we like.

Does this look like a workable solution or is there a simpler way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 2 magento versions.
Magento supports different themes on the same store view for different devices.
All you need to to is to configure a different theme.
For this go to: `System->Configuration->Design`, select each store view from the top left selector, or `Default config` if you want to use the same theme for all languages.
In the `Theme` section you can click on the `Add Exception` button under the field you need changed (most probably all that support exceptions) and fill in the following.
`Matched Expression` - `iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini`
`Value` - `The name of your mobile theme`.

Comment: Ah great, is there a limit to the number of themes in that case. If I run 1000 different themes on each store view would Magento cope?

Comment: @AndrewMiles. This is actually a different question. A very good one but a different one. I've never worked with more than 4 themes per magento instance. I don't see any reasons for this not to work but I may be missing something. Maybe you have more luck with this new question on http://magento.stackexchange.com